# Uploading a jpg to firebase storage does not completely upload the file

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am trying to write a function that uploads a jpeg image to firebase storage and returns the download link of the uploaded file. But when I execute the function, the file does not completely upload to the storage i.e. original file size is 10 KB and uploaded file size is 9 B. I'm using the following code:

```
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const dpRef = storageRef.child("users/dp.jpg").put(file, {
      contentType: "image/jpeg",
    });

    dpRef.on(
      firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
      (snapshot) => {
        // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
        var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
        switch (snapshot.state) {
          case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
            console.log("Upload is paused");
            break;
          case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
            console.log("Upload is running");
            console.log(progress);
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        // A full list of error codes is available at
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors
        switch (error.code) {
          case "storage/unauthorized":
            // User doesn't have permission to access the object
            console.log("Unauthorized");
            break;
          case "storage/canceled":
            // User canceled the upload
            console.log("Cancelled");
            break;

          // ...

          case "storage/unknown":
            // Unknown error occurred, inspect error.serverResponse
            console.log("Unknown");
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      },
      () => {
        // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
        dpRef.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
          console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
        });
      }
    );
```

The `console.log(progress)` shows NaN for some reason. I also tried download

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the problem, but I did this recently and I can share my code:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';

const uploadImageFetch = async (uri) => {
    const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function () {
            resolve(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
        };
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.open('GET', uri, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    });
    const imageNameBefore = uri.split('/');
    const imageName = imageNameBefore[imageNameBefore.length - 1];

    const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(`images/${imageName}`);
    const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);
    blob.close();
    return await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
};
```

This function accept a local URI with the image, and returns the download URL.
You can see more examples in the official Documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Comment: I tried your code but the output is the same i.e. only 9 B shown as the file size for the uploaded photo in the firebase storage. And when I download the photo, its broken and does not open.

Comment: Aren't you getting any error in console? Check your firebase initialization and authentication.